# How configure job execution for sudo users with NOPASSWD option?

Tags: rundeck

I try run command from another user remotely from rundeck jobs.
Rundeck provide sudo login\passwod mechanism for escalate privilege.
On my remote server in sudoers file NOPASSWD option. How i can configure rundeck jobs in this case?

my node configurations:

```
<project>
        <node name="testServer"
                type="Node"
                description="testNode"
                hostname="IP_ADDRESS"
                username="${option.Login}"
                ssh-authentication="password"
                sudo-command-enabled="true"
                ssh-password-option="option.Password"
                />

</project>
```

Example command in job for become another user:

```
sudo /bin/su suuser -
```

Error's after trying executions:

```
Remote command failed with exit status -1
08:57:13            Sudo execution password response failed: Failed waiting for input prompt: Expected input was not seen in 5000 milliseconds
08:57:13            Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following three attributes to my node and it appears to work:

`sudo-command-enabled="true"`

`sudo-prompt-pattern=""`

`sudo-command-pattern="^sudo.*"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the below attributes in Edit Project Configuration File

```
project.ssh-authentication=password
project.ssh-keypath=/home/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa
project.ssh-password-storage-path=keys/xyz.password
project.sudo-command-enabled=true
project.sudo-password-option=option.jobPassword
project.sudo-password-storage-path=keys/xyz.password
project.sudo-prompt-pattern=^Password\:.*
```